# Is it possible for beginners to suggest tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Seriously is it possible to let beginners suggest tags? I tried to create the tag *XFCE-desktop* which is the large package I had to reinstall, but was told I did not have 300 points. It is more to the point with XFCE-desktop than just the tag XFCE. I have learned that precision is crucial when solving problems and thought that precise tags would have the same principles.

Comment: You can ask nicely for someone to create it for you, however I don't see a need for a tag for every package.

Comment: Can you please enlighten me about how your question title is related to the question body? I'm confused...

Comment: You can ask a mod (except that mod that has 150 reputation for some reason), or me, or anyone with 300+ reputation. Also i'm curious: is creating a tag free or it wastes off 300 reputation?

Comment: @StarOS The only actions that cost reputation are offering bounties (costs the value of the bounty) and downvoting answers (costs 1 reputation point, returned to you if the post gets deleted later). In general, reputation increases unlock moderation / site management abilities on SE. You do not use up the points gained when using these abilities, which in general benefit the site and have little obvious value for the person doing them except that making the site better helps everyone.

Answer (score 6):

Tags are for classifying questions, and thereby allowing people who are interested in a particular topic focus on that topic. If a tag is too narrow, few people will be interested in it, and it becomes useless. If a tag is too broad, people will pick narrower tags.

No one is interested in the `xfce-desktop` package ...  because [there is no such package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xfce-desktop). Assuming that you meant `xubuntu-desktop`, why would anyone be interested in that package specifically? People are interested in Xubuntu or XFCE. Virtually no one (except the maintainer) cares about that package. Even you, who wants to create a tag named after it, wouldn't give two bits about it once your problem is solved and you don't have to touch that package again.